# Jest chained functions with iterator

Tags: javascript, jestjs, suitescript2.0

I am trying to mock an iterator that is used within SuiteScript Map Reduce to be able to iterate through the errors and determine whether errors occured and an email should be sent.

Within the code it looks like this.

```js
reduceContext.errors.iterator().each(function(key, error, executionNo) {
    console.debug(error);
    errors.push(JSON.parse(error));
    return true;
});
```

I have tried something like the following to be able to mock so it actually calls each, but can't get it to successfully log.

`ReduceContext` is already a stub that is mocked.

I tried setting up errors with the following mocks which worked to make sure there were no errors.

```js
ReduceContext.errors = {
    iterator: jest.fn((array) => {
        for (const i=0; i<array.length; i++) {
            this.each(array[i].key, array[i].error, i);
        }
        return this;
    })
    , each: jest.fn()
};
```

Then within the test I tried to do the following, but the code within the `.each` will never get called.

```js
ReduceContext.errors.iterator.mockReturnValue([{key: 1, error: "test"}]);
```